# Adruino with ethernetshield and boost server can't connect

Tags: boost, arduino, boost-asio, shared-ptr

Iim programming a tcp/ip pc/arduino project. The Arduino has a ethernetshield and serves as client. The PC runs boost and makes use of the asio library and serves as client.

When i try to connect to the server the connection can not be establised. The server has a network adapter that has the static aderes of 192.168.1.1. And the Arduino has IP adress of 192.168.1.2. The two are directly connected with a UTP cable. Both are using port 5000.

For the Arduino code i use a sample program to for testing but this fails. The setup looks like this:

```
// Enter the IP address of the server you're connecting to:
IPAddress server(192,168,1,1); 

// Initialize the Ethernet client library
// with the IP address and port of the server 
// that you want to connect to (port 23 is default for telnet;
// if you're using Processing's ChatServer, use  port 10002):
EthernetClient client;

void setup() {
   // start the Ethernet connection:
   Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
   // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
Serial.begin(9600);
 while (!Serial) {
  ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
}


 // give the Ethernet shield a second to initialize:
 delay(1000);
 Serial.println("connecting...");

 // if you get a connection, report back via serial:
 if (client.connect(server, 5000)) {
   Serial.println("connected");
 } 
 else {
   // if you didn't get a connection to the server:
   Serial.println("connection failed");
 }
}
```

The PC server code is also fairly simple, in a class constructor i do the following:

```
    cout << "Setting up server" << endl;
    // Protocol and port
     boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint Endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), 5000);

    // Create acceptor
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor Acceptor(IOService, Endpoint);

    // Create socket
    SmartSocket Sock(new boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket(IOService));

    cout << "Before accept..." << endl;

     // Waiting for client
         Acceptor.accept(*Sock);

    cout << "Server set up" << endl;
```

SmartSocket is a typdef:

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> SmartSocket;
```

I i start the server the console prints "Before Accept" and waits in the accept function for a incomming client. But when i run my Arduino code then i get connection failed (in the ardunion serial monitor).

Does anybody have some idea's what is going wrong? It seems that the server and client don't see each other. I also put down my firewall but this didn't help. Any comments are usefull!

Comment: Is it possible to use boost to connect to a arduino with a ethernetshield?

Comment: if "arduino with a ethernetshield" accept TCP connections, you can establish them using Boost.Asio. Use some sniffer (like Wireshark) to see what's going on between your client and server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be any number of reasons for a server and client not communicating.  From a bug in the code, a firewall blocking the messages, NIC settings or the devices simply not being connected. Which is much more common than you'd believe!

To ensure that your connection is OK, try to `ping` the PC from the Ardunio.

To ensure that your asio PC server code is OK. Try making a local TCP connection to it like an HTTP request. E.g. type `http://127.0.0.1:5000/hello` in your web browser url on the PC. This will send a GET request on the localhost to your server on port 5000, which should at least print out "Server set up" on your PC's console.

If not, try using port 80 (the standard TCP port) instead of 5000 in your PC server code and the request. If that works then it's likely that a firewall is blocking your port or you've got a bug in your Adruino code

However, if that doesn't work, then you need to look closely at your server code. The asio [Daytime.2](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime2.html) example should work for you.

Also take @Igor's advice and install `Wireshark` on your PC. It may be free, but it's priceless when it comes to debugging network problems.